# Parse '+' symbol as '+' instead of space ' ' while sending requests in expressjs

Tags: express, encoding

When I make a request to express server running in the back-end, I pass a mathematical expression as data along with the request. This is done so that I can retrieve the expression as it is at server side. But when I send an expression such as '3+2=5' (String), the data I get when I access req.body at server side is
'3 2:5'. The problem is that + is encoded into space. I don't want that to happen.
What steps should i take?

This is my request part (using superagent package)

```
request
    .post('/insertdata')
    .send(newItem)
    .end(function(err,res){
      if(err||!res.ok){
        console.log('Oh no! err');
      } else {
        console.log('Success');
      }
    });
```

Here insertdata is my express route to invoke. newItem = "3+2=5" (Checked by logging).

This is my route handler for the above request.

```
app.use(parser.json());
app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.post('/insertdata',function(req,res){
var newData = req.body;
console.log(newData);
.
.
.
}
```

Here logging newData outputs {3 2: 5}. I would rather want {3+2: 5}.

parser is required from body-parser package for parsing URLs.

Please suggest how to tackle this issue........

Comment: `+` has to be escaped as `%2b`. Because `+` in the url encoding of a value represents a space.

Comment: so instead of + I should store %2b in the string "3+2=5"??

Comment: Like this "3 \%2b = 5" ????

Comment: If the lib/tool that does the request, has no option to encode that data, then you would need convert it yourself, so that the resulting query value looks that way `3%2B2=5`.